# Are there any drawbacks to using <button> instead of <input type="submit"> if I'm not supporting IE6/7?

Tags: html, button, icon-fonts

The reason for my question is I'd like to use a search icon from an icon font, which I can't think of a good way to do with an input. I know IE6 and maybe 7 had some quirks with buttons, but if I'm not supporting those, are there any drawbacks to just using a `<button>` tag?

With a `<button>` tag I can just use the required html inside the tag.

Comment: There is no problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The button element represents a button labeled by its contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element).

A `<button>` can contain [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) (except for other interactive content such as `<input>`).

In my experience there's no problem using a `<button>` instead of an `<input type=button>`.  IE7- will submit the `<button>`'s *contents*, which is odd.  That's pretty much all you have to worry about, though.

Comment: Ah thanks for that. That's a pretty serious problem and maybe big enough for me to not use `<button>` even though I'm not technically supporting IE6/7. It sounds like it would render the search unusable.